# Function to check if an integer is valid in PHP

Tags: php, validation, integer

Is there a function in PHP that returns true if a string/int could be safely converted into an int? 
like so:

```
var_dump(f('1'));//returns true
var_dump(f(1));//returns true
var_dump(f('1.2'));//returns false
var_dump(f(-2));//returns true
var_dump(f('3x'));//returns false
```

I do not care about bases.
I checked out is_int, but is_int('4') returns false.
I could use a cast/intval, but:
`intval('6x')` returns 6, and `intval('x')` returns 0 as does `intval(0)` and `intval('0')`

Comment: `function f ($i) { return "$i" === "".(int)$i; }`

Comment: Nice one, but i would prefer a more native solution, with documentation and whatnot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
if (filter_var('1', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
     echo 'int'."<br>";
}
if (!filter_var('dog', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
     echo 'not int'."<br>";
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/V7NInq)

Answer (score -2):

The function is_int() is what you should use.

The reason why

```
is_int('4')
```

will return false is because it's not an integer. When you add quotes around the integer PHP will assume it's a string - hence the "false" return.

Try this out:

```
is_int(4)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the whole point is to check if a string is an int.

Comment: A string is not an integer, that's just a basic datatype fact. Do you want to check if a string CONTAINS an integer?

Comment: No, a string is not an integer.But I want to check if a given string can be safely converted into an int.

Comment: Alright, then you should listen to @John Conde. Good luck! :)